Why is my autohotkey script with a loop and if statement does not work?
I've been trying to make a script where at specific minutes every hours, something happen. I've tried to add a loop so it can always check if it is now at the right minute of the hour. I tested the loop with a mouse click and it worked, I'm pretty sure the problem is when combining the if statement with a loop. I've been stuck for 1 hours trying to think of a way to fix it or find another way to do it.
^!p::


time:
formattime, time, , mm tt

 loop  
 {
   if (Time = "59 am")
      {
       goto action1
      }
   if (Time = "45 am")
      {
       goto action2
      }
   if (Time = "03 am")
      {
       goto action3
      }
   }
Return

action3:
 {
   msgbox, test
 }
return

action2:
 {
   msgbox, test2
 }
return

action1:
 {
   msgbox, test3
 }
return

Esc::ExitApp  ; Exit script with Escape key


Try this:
^!p::

loop {
  If (A_Hour > 12)  ; to work only at am time
    Continue
  Switch  A_Min {
    Case 59: ; any hour in am at 59 min
       goto action1
   Case 45: ; any hour in am at 45 min
       goto action2
   Case 3: ; any hour in am at 3 min
       goto action3
  }
}
Return

action3:
   msgbox, test
return

action2:
   msgbox, test2
return

action1:
   msgbox, test3
return


Esc::ExitApp  ; Exit script with Escape key

